# How can I avoid the need to cast to (ServiceException) in the following code?

Tags: c#

I created an exception class like this:

```
public class ServiceException : ApplicationException {

    public Dictionary<string, string> Errors { get; set; }

    public ServiceException(Exception ex) : base("Service Exception", ex) {
      Errors = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }
    public ServiceException() : this(null) {}

}
```

The following code fails:

```
protected void log(Exception ex)
{
    if (ex is ServiceException)
    {
        var y = (ServiceException)
        ModelState.Merge(ex.Errors);
    }
    else
    {
        Trace.Write(ex);
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Database access error: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

It generates the following error on compile:

> Error 5 'System.Exception' does not contain a definition for 'Errors'
>   and no extension method 'Errors' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Exception' could be found (are you missing a using directive
>   or an assembly reference?)

I fixed it by doing the following:

```
if (ex is ServiceException)
{
    var y = (ServiceException)ex;
    ModelState.Merge(y.Errors);
}
```

Is there some way that I can avoid this messy code using a variable y and then casting it ? Without declaring the intermediate variable y the code does not pass a syntax check.

Comment: You need to talk with a lisp: ModelState.Merge(((ServiceException)ex).Errors);

Comment: In C# one way or the either you must use a cast to make the compiler happy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast because ex is not a `ServiceException`. The `is` operator is simply evaluating telling you that it is a `ServiceException`, but doesn't perform the cast to the type.

Think about what type ex is. It's of type `Exception`, and generally speaking you don't know what it is. By calling `ex is ServiceException`, you're checking if the dynamic type of `ex` is `ServiceException`. But the static type is still `Exception`. That doesn't change.

C# is a statically typed language, so the *static* type of `ex`, which is `Exception` won't magically change to `ServiceException` after you use the `is` operator. You still need to cast it yourself.

Rather, you may wish to use the as operator:

```
protected void log(Exception ex)
{
    ServiceException se = ex as ServiceException;
    if (se != null)
        ModelState.Merge(se.Errors);
    else
    {
        Trace.Write(ex);
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Database access error: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

`ex as ServiceException` tries to cast `ex` to a `ServiceException`. If `ex` isn't a `ServiceException`, the cast fails and it returns null.

Alternatively, if you're really against using an extra local variable, then you can just cast it and then use it immediately:

```
if (se is ServiceException)
    ModelState.Merge(((ServiceException) se).Errors);
```

Honestly though, I don't see why you'd want this though. Doing the check first (using `as` or `is`) followed by using the downcasted exception is the best idea here. It's cleaner to actually use the extra variable because you're showing your intent and it's immediately obvious what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to cast it, but you could just do it inline:

```
if (ex is ServiceException) 
        { 
            ModelState.Merge(((ServiceException)ex).Errors); 
        }
```

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to cast, just that I would do it differently.

```
 try
    {
    ...
    }
    catch(ServiceException ex)
    {
        logException(ex);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        logException(ex);
    }

public void logException(ex)
{
    if(ex is ServiceException)
    {
        logServiceException(ex as ServiceException)
    }
    else
    {
        logGenericException(ex)
    }   
}

private void logGenericException(Exception ex)
{
...
}
```

**No need to cast in the following method**

```
 private void logServiceException(ServiceException ex)
    {
    //now there is no need to do a cast
    }
```